# How to call method in DynamicMethod generated body

Tags: c#, methods, dynamic

I'm trying to create a sort of WCF communication between 2 software (To challenge myself).

What I mean by WCF is beeing able to have an interface as a contract in a Shared library. Then being able to use that contract in my two software. 
I would like to use them as we do in WCf that mean as if the client was calling a simple method from the same software but in fact that use a TcpClient calling a TcpServer on the other side ....

As WCF I would like to be generic, so I dont want pre-built class that wrap my network logic for a specific contract. 
As WCF I would like to be able to write a contract interface, then create a new instance of a the say "ClientBase" class, with my contract as template parameters, then use this client as a "Remote" of my other software.

As an exemple is always better here is what I would like :

In a shared project :

```
public interface IFooContract
{
    void Add(int a, int b);
}
```

In the client :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new ClientFooContract())
        {
            var result = client.Add(5, 2);
        }
    }
}

class ClientFooContract : MyClientBase<IFooContract>, IFooContract, IDisposable
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return Channel.Add(a, b);
    }
}

class MyClientBase<T> where T : class
{
    protected T Channel;

    public MyClientBase()
    {
        Channel = /*Create Channel instance*/
    }
}
```

My implementation is really close to th basics of WCF, but my issue is creating the Channel Instance, because of course I do not have any class that I can instantiate. I need a sort of dynamic class the implement that specific contract and for each method of this contract, handle the network logic for creating a TcpClient, connecting it to a remote server, sending data, waiting response and returning the result to the ClientFooContract.

Of course I could create a ChannelBase class that implement the contract and handle network for each of these method, but I would like to be generic as WCF, beeing able to provide any type of contract to my system.

I'm currently working with the Emit namespace trying to build dynamic class that contain method for now, here it my non finished code for creating an method :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var methods = new List<Method>();

        methods.Add(new Method()
        {
            Name = "Add",
            Params = new List<MethodParam>()
            {
                new MethodParam()
                {
                    Name = "a",
                    Type = typeof(int)
                },
                new MethodParam()
                {
                    Name = "b",
                    Type = typeof(int)
                }
            },
            ReturnType = typeof(int)
        });

        MyTypeBuilder.CompileResultType(methods);
    }
}

public class Method
{
    public string Name;
    public List<MethodParam> Params;
    public Type ReturnType;
}

public class MethodParam
{
    public string Name;
    public Type Type;
}

public static class MyTypeBuilder
{
    public static Type CompileResultType(List<Method> methodList)
    {
        TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder();
        ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

        if (methodList != null)
            foreach (var method in methodList)
                CreateMethod(tb, method);

        Type objectType = tb.CreateType();

        return objectType;
    }

    private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
    {
        var typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
        var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        //AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
        TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature,
                TypeAttributes.Public |
                TypeAttributes.Class |
                TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
                null,
                new Type[] { typeof(IFoo) });

        return tb;
    }

    private static void CreateMethod(TypeBuilder tb, Method method)
    {
        MethodBuilder methodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod(method.Name, MethodAttributes.Public, method.ReturnType, method.Params.Select(l => l.Type).ToArray());
        ILGenerator il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
    }
}
```

Here is my struggle, I dont know how to add body to my dynamic method, I found on internet few exemples on how to create local variable etc etc , But actualy how can I create a TcpClient with the IL, do I need to place all of that in a separate method then call this method ? and how ? 
How actualy can I make a simple call to a console.writeLine to actualy test my system ?

My issue is really the creation of the MethodBody, becauseI will have to do a lots of work here, not just declaring local variable and handle basic operations.
If there is at least a way to call an other method on an other class it will be helpfull

If you know anything, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

After few hours testing I finally found the solution, for my method body issue.

Here it is with comment (in case someone, one day ends up in this topic).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Init List of method that I want to create
        var methods = new List<Method>();

        methods.Add(new Method()
        {
            Name = "Add",
            Params = new List<MethodParam>()
            {
                new MethodParam()
                {
                    Name = "a",
                    Type = typeof(int)
                },
                new MethodParam()
                {
                    Name = "b",
                    Type = typeof(int)
                }
            },
            ReturnType = typeof(int)
        });

        // Compile my type
        var myType = MyTypeBuilder.CompileResultType(methods);

        // Create instance of my type
        var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType) as IFooContract;

        // Call Function
        var result = myObject.Add(5, 2);

        // Log
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        Console.Read();
    }
}

// Used to store Method Infos
public class Method
{
    public string Name;
    public List<MethodParam> Params;
    public Type ReturnType;
}

// Used to store Method param's Infos
public class MethodParam
{
    public string Name;
    public Type Type;
}

// Builder for the Dynamic class
public static class MyTypeBuilder
{
    public static Type CompileResultType(List<Method> methodList)
    {
        TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder();
        ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

        if (methodList != null)
        {
            // Loop throught all method definition
            foreach (var method in methodList)
            {
                // Generate new method on the dynamic class
                CreateMethod(tb, method);
            }
        }

        // Create the Dynamic class
        Type objectType = tb.CreateType();

        return objectType;
    }

    private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
    {
        var typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
        var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
        TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature,
                TypeAttributes.Public |
                TypeAttributes.Class |
                TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
                null,
                new Type[] { typeof(IFooContract) }); // <= Interface that the Dynamic class will implement (used for intellisens)

        tb.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IFooContract)); // <= Specify that the class will implement that interface

        return tb;
    }

    private static void CreateMethod(TypeBuilder tb, Method method)
    {
        // Create Method builder
        MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod(method.Name, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, method.ReturnType, method.Params.Select(x => x.Type).ToArray());

        // Get the IL Generator
        ILGenerator il = mb.GetILGenerator();


        // Start Build Method Body :

        // Load first parameter on evaluation stack
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

        // Load Second parameter on evaluation stack
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2);

        // Use the two last element loaded as operand for "+" operation
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Add);

        // Push the last element on evaluation stack as return of the function
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // Stop Build Method Body


        // Explicitly set this new function as the implementation of the interface function
        MethodInfo interfaceMethod = typeof(IFooContract).GetMethod(method.name);
        tb.DefineMethodOverride(mb, interfaceMethod);
    }
}
```